# Is it possible to mute / disable error responses with the google-assistant-sdk?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I've got the google-assistant-library running on my pi. I'm using device actions.  I don't want the assistant to respond to anything but the action I've registered. If it fails to understand my intent, or thinks I'm asking about the weather, I just want it to remain mute. (I know that's a terrible user experience generally, but this is for a theatric kind of setting).

Is that possible?